# Can't convert string to number in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, string, buffer, node-red

A modbus flex getter returns a buffer

[118,48,49,49,48,56,61,57,52,54,46,54,52,0,0,0,0,0]

converted to a string with

```
var bufstr = msg.payload.buffer.toString();
var bufarr = bufstr.split("=");
msg.payload = bufarr[1];

return msg;
```

the output to the debugging window is
msg.payload : string[11]
"946.64"

but if i want to convert the string to a number with a change node and JsonATA
`$number(payload)`
it drops the error

> Ungültiger JSONata Ausdruck: Unable to cast value to a number: "946.64\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"

Even with
`string.Number(msg.payload);`
it does return NaN.

It seems there is a problem with the encoding, the last four zeroes of the buffer are converted to something Node-RED doesn't display.

The number has various digits and possibly a point.

A regex with /(^0-9.-)/ didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution:

```
var i = 0;
var buf = msg.payload.buffer;

while (i < buf.length)
{
    if (buf[i] == 0)
        buf[i] = 32;
    i++;
}

var bufstr = buf.toString();
var bufarr = bufstr.split("=");
msg.payload = Number(bufarr[1]);

return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `toString()` function on the buffer, and pair it thie the `.trim()` function which will remove the trailing white space. The `\00` characters are null and will be removed.